# Group by help required in query

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, case

Below query is giving me 2 rows for 9 week having 1st row 
13hrs of REG_HRS and 2nd row of 
5hrs of OT_HRS

I want all values for 9th week in single row

```
Select VP.PERSONID as EMPL,
VP.HOMELABORLEVELNM3 as DEPT,
--TO_CHAR(X.APPLYDTM, 'DD-MM-YYYY') AS LABOR_DATE,
to_char(X.APPLYDTM - 7/24,'IW') AS WEEK,
Case when P.NAME = 'US-ABS' then SUM(X.DURATIONSECSQTY/3600.0) else 0 end as ABS_HRS,
Case when P.NAME = 'US-Regular' then SUM(X.DURATIONSECSQTY/3600.0) else 0 end as REG_HRS,
Case when P.NAME = 'US-Overtime' then  SUM(X.DURATIONSECSQTY/3600.0) else 0 end as OT_HRS,
Case when P.NAME = 'US-Doubletime' then SUM(X.DURATIONSECSQTY/3600.0) else 0 end as DBL_HRS,
Case when P.NAME = 'US-VAC' then SUM(X.DURATIONSECSQTY/3600.0) else 0 end as VAC_HRS,
Case when P.NAME = 'US-HOL' then SUM(X.DURATIONSECSQTY/3600.0) else 0 end as HOL_HRS,
SUM(X.DURATIONSECSQTY/3600.0) AS Totals,
Case when P.NAME = 'US-ABS' and SUM(X.WAGEAMT) != 0 then SUM(X.WAGEAMT) else 0 end as ABS_DLRS,
Case when P.NAME = 'US-Regular' and SUM(X.WAGEAMT) != 0 then SUM (X.WAGEAMT) else 0 end as REG_DLRS,
Case when P.NAME = 'US-Overtime' and SUM(X.WAGEAMT) != 0 then SUM(X.WAGEAMT) else 0 end as OT_DLRS,
Case when P.NAME = 'US-Doubletime' and SUM(X.WAGEAMT) != 0 then SUM(X.WAGEAMT) else 0 end as DBL_DLRS,
Case when P.NAME = 'US-VAC' and SUM(X.WAGEAMT) != 0 then SUM(X.WAGEAMT) else 0 end as VAC_DLRS,
Case when P.NAME = 'US-HOL' and SUM(X.WAGEAMT) != 0 then SUM(X.WAGEAMT) else 0 end as HOL_DLRS,
Case when P.NAME in ('USKEANE- Shift Prem','USKEANE- Shift Prem OT','USKEANE- Shift Prem DT') then SUM(X.DURATIONSECSQTY/3600.0) else 0 end as NITE_PREM
from VP_EMPLOYEEV42 VP,
WFCTOTAL X,
PAYCODE P
where 
VP.PERSONID = X.EMPLOYEEID and 
X.PAYCODEID = P.PAYCODEID and
--X.EMPLOYEEID = CA.PERSONID and
--CA.CUSTOMDATADEFID ='153' and
--X.TIMESHEETITEMID = TS.TIMESHEETITEMID and
P.NAME in ('US-Regular','US-Overtime','US-Doubletime','USKEANE- Shift Prem','USKEANE- Shift Prem OT','USKEANE- Shift Prem DT') AND
X.EMPLOYEEID in (select personid from PERSONCSTMDATA where CUSTOMDATADEFID ='154' and PERSONCSTMDATATXT = 'USKEANE')
and VP.PERSONID = '13702' 
and X.APPLYDTM between '28-FEB-19' and '01-MAR-19' 
group by VP.PERSONID, VP.HOMELABORLEVELNM3, P.NAME, to_char(X.APPLYDTM - 7/24,'IW')
ORDER BY VP.PERSONID
```

Comment: A `case` expression's different result values must have compatible data types. What does Oracle think about VARCHAR(15) combined with integer?

Comment: Remove comma from `cast(X.WAGEAMT, AS`.

Comment: @jarlh Oracle doesn't like it...it doesn't like it one bit! :P

Comment: Thanks got output, also I want to eliminate else part of this case statement

Comment: It is creating rows with 0 values that I don't want

Comment: Do you want `ELSE NULL`? Or do you want to add a `WHERE REG_DOLLARS = 0`? Please show more of your query and expected results.

Comment: with case statement I get column name as REG_DOLLAR but if p.name is not "US-Regular" then it is creating rows with 0 value in column REG_DOLLAR and I don't want that values in output. I hope you get my point

Comment: Post the full query.

Comment: Posted the query

Answer (score 1):

Oracle uses the ANSI standard `||` for string concatenation:

```
CASE WHEN p.NAME = 'US-Regular'
     THEN '$' || CAST(x.WAGEAMT AS VARCHAR(15))
     ELSE '0' END AS REG_DOLLARS
```

Also, all branches of a `CASE` expression need to have the same type.  Since in your `THEN` branch you are committing to using text, your `ELSE` branch should also contain text.

Comment: Then maybe the rest of your query has some problem.  The code I gave above should not be throwing this error.

Comment: got output and how to eliminate else output from query?

Comment: What do you mean by "eliminate" `ELSE` output from the query?  There is _always_ an `ELSE` condition in a `CASE` expression, even if you don't explicitly include one.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . This was not the answer I saw when I responded.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Weird...because I don't remember fumbling it actually.  Gordon, I love you more than peanut butter, just not when you double post on everyone's answers :P

Comment: with case statement I get column name as REG_DOLLAR but if p.name is not "US-Regular" then it is creating rows with 0 value and I don't want that values in output. I hope you get my point

Comment: Stop commenting here, and instead edit your question with the actual full query you are using.